# Fast/Memory-Conserving Manner to remove vectors from array if they are too close in Euclidean Space

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, matrix, memory-management

In order to make clustering a more feasible task, I want to remove items from an array if they have another item which is within some threshold in n-dimensional euclidean space. The input data into this truncation is an array of pixel-wise feature vectors. My first thought was to compute the pairwise euclidean distance matrix between all the items and then operate on them as such:

```
indices = list(range(len(X)))
dist_matrix = euclidean_distances(X,X)

index = 0
while True:
    deletion = np.where(dist_matrix[index]<=threshold)[0]
    indices = [i for i in indices if i==index or i not in deletion]
    try:
        index = indices[indices.index(index) + 1]
    except IndexError:
        break

dictionary = []
for index in indices:
    dictionary.append(X[index])
```

However, this leads to a Memory Error for my large dataset when creating the distance matrix with sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances. What is an effective, memory-conservative manner to perform this operation? I've realized that the computation of this distance matrix is what is causing problems in the clustering algorithm, so I would like to be able to avoid the computation of such a large distance matrix by truncating the input array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of dimensions n, number of points N, the size of the problem in each dimension L, and your acceptable separation distance d, one option would be to grid your space into boxes of dimension d and retain at most one point within each grid box. Memory requirement would change from O(N^2) to O((L/d)^n), and running time would change from O(N^2) to O(N + (L/d)^n), so it might be more efficient if L/d and n are not too large.

Alternately, it might be practical to use the following algorithm

```
 for each point p in points
   for each point q in points
     if p <> q and p.dist(q) < Dmin
       q.delete
```

This should be O(N^2) running time and O(0) extra memory.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try and see if this works for my data (it's high-dimensional and has a large (>100K) dictionary size) tomorrow.

Comment: I've used your gridding idea (going to answer my own question then accept your answer) with some modifications and it worked quite well! I haven't tried your second answer yet, but the vector array is actually a flattened 2-Dimensional vector image, so I'm not sure if it would get rid of enough vectors to make the clustering task feasible.

Answer (score 0):

A KD tree should be faster/more efficient than your base approach, and scipy has a nice implementation for your use case. The runtime is O(nlog(n)), and while I'm not sure about the memory use one would assume it's only storing the pairs you'll want to delete.

Pengiuno's recommendation of grid sampling method is probably even faster from a runtime perspective, but using scipy requires less additional coding on your part.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_tree

Comment: Sadly I'm dealing with high-dimensionality data, which the KDTree is inefficient at handling according to literature. I will still try it though!

Comment: Although this was a good idea, the KDTree cannot be fed into HDBScan, the clustering algorithm I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

By Penguino's suggestion, I've gridded the hyperrectangle containing my points. Since the number of dimensions is undefined (I have multiple vector lengths that I'm dealing with at different points), I can't actually partition the space without recursion (I'm being slightly lazy with this), so I've created a workaround based upon splitting each dimension into *d* chunks. I'm selecting a number of points in each chunk based upon the relative density of that chunk. This operation is slightly costly, but a decent workaround in terms of memory conservation. Another workaround is to chunk the list of vectors and compute the pairwise distance matrix for each chunk and recursively build up the reduced vector list.

```
def ndimcube_grid(X,ndim,d):
    dictionary = []
    for n in range(ndim):
        maximum = np.amax(X[:,n])
        minimum = np.amin(X[:,n])
        chunk = (maximum - minimum)/d
        iterate = minimum
        lengths = []
        while iterate < maximum:
            a = np.where(X[:,n] < (iterate + chunk))[0]
            b = np.where(X[:,n] >= iterate)[0]
            indices = list(set(a) & set(b))
            lengths.append(len(indices))
            iterate += chunk

        min_length = np.amin([length for length in lengths if not(length == 0)])
        iterate = minimum
        while iterate < maximum:
            a = np.where(X[:,n] < (iterate + chunk))[0]
            b = np.where(X[:,n] >= iterate)[0]
            indices = list(set(a) & set(b))
            size = int(np.round(len(indices)/min_length))
            MAX_DENSITY = 25
            size = np.minimum(size,MAX_DENSITY)
            if size > 0:
                selections = np.random.choice(indices,size=size)
                try:
                    for selection in selections:
                        if len(dictionary) > 0:
                            if np.amin(euclidean_distances(dictionary,X[selection]))>ndim:
                                dictionary.append(X[selection])
                        else:
                            dictionary.append(X[selection])
                except TypeError:
                    dictionary.append(selections)
            iterate += chunk

    return np.array(dictionary)
```